# How to loop through items in a js object?

Tags: javascript, json, loops

how can I loop through these items?

```
var userCache = {};
userCache['john']     = {ID: 234, name: 'john', ... };
userCache['mary']     = {ID: 567, name: 'mary', ... };
userCache['douglas']  = {ID: 42,  name: 'douglas', ... };
```

the length property doesn't work?

```
userCache.length
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can loop over the properties (`john`, `mary` and `douglas`) of your `userCache` object as follows:

```
for (var prop in userCache) {
    if (userCache.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        // You will get each key of the object in "prop".
        // Therefore to access your items you should be using:
        //     userCache[prop].name;
        //     userCache[prop].ID;
        //     ...
    }
}
```

It is important to use the [`hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) method, to determine whether the object has the specified property as a direct property, and not inherited from the object's prototype chain.

Comment: @Blankman: What this does is set `prop` to each key contained with the object, in a loop. So `prop` will be "john", "mary", "douglas", etc. (in *no* defined order, it depends on the Javascript implementation and the direction of the wind that day). Thus, inside the loop, you can do `alert(userCache[prop].name)` to get the `name` property of each of the objects stored in the cache.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i in userCache){
   alert(i+'='+userCache[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you would use a for.. in loop

```
for (var prop in userCache) {
    if (userCache.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        alert("userCache has property " + prop + " with value " + userCache[prop]);
    }
}
```

The `.hasOwnProperty is needed to avoid members inherited through the prototype chain.

Answer (score 0):

there's no `length` property because you're not using an indexed array.

see here for iterating over the properties.

[Difference in JSON objects using Javascript/JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200562/difference-in-json-objects-using-javascript-jquery/1200713#1200713)