# Retrieving labels from JSON objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Say I have JSON data as below:

```
var db=[
        {"name":"John Doe","age":25},
        {"name":"John Doe 2","age":21}
       ]
```

I know how to retrieve data from the JSON object using js/jquery. What I need is to get the value of the labels, i.e. I want to retrieve the "name" and the "age" from the object. I don't actually want to retrieve the values "John Doe" and 25 (I can already do that), instead I want the labels.

Say the JSON object has about 5 data with 10 fields each. I need to display the JSON in table form dynamically which I can already do. Since the JSON may be any set of values, I won't know what label to put in the `<th></th>` cells of the table. So I need a way to get the labels.

Using a pseudo code:

```
var db=[
        {"name":"John Doe","age":25},
        {"name":"John Doe 2","age":21}
       ]    
for i in db{
    for j in db[i]{
          console.log(db[i][j].label+":"db[i][j])
    }  
}
//db[i][j].label doesn't really work
```

The output should be:

name: John Doe

age: 25

name: John Doe

age: 21

Is there a JavaScript or jQuery function to do so or some other method to retrieve the required data?

Comment: Once loaded the JSON data is just an object. You can just iterate over the properties/keys of the object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208016/how-to-list-the-properties-of-a-javascript-object

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript: Getting all existing keys in a JSON array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767133/javascript-getting-all-existing-keys-in-a-json-array)

Comment: i would suggest using for(i=0;i<yourarray.length;i++) in your first iteration tho for the reason? read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're already fetching the property name (which you are calling "label"). You need it to get the property's value out of the object.

So, it's just `j`.

```
console.log(j + ":" + db[i][j]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Once loaded the JSON data is just an object (in your case an array of objects). You can just iterate over the properties/keys of each single object.

### e.g.

```
$.each(db, function(index, object) {
    for (var property in object) {
        var val = object[property];
        // do stuff
        console.log("property: " + property + ", val: " + val);
    }
});
```

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/5hkr8k2x/

Answer (score 1):

You could look at using the `jQuery.each` function:

```
$.each(db, function(index, record) {
    $.each(record, function(key, value) {
        console.log(key + ': ' + value);
    });
});
```