# best practice for search data at json object id using map

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, typescript

Let me how to find a json in javascript.
Sample Json:

```
   {
"Employees" : [
{
"userId":"rirani",
"jobTitleName":"Developer",

"preferredFullName":"Romin Irani",
"employeeCode":"E1",
"region":"CA",
"phoneNumber":"408-1234567",
"emailAddress":"romin.k.irani@gmail.com"
},
{
"userId":"nirani",
"jobTitleName":"Developer",    
"preferredFullName":"Neil Irani",
"employeeCode":"E2",
"region":"CA",
"phoneNumber":"408-1111111",
"emailAddress":"neilrirani@gmail.com"
}
]
]
}
```

the above json i want find particular userId based on employeeCode,emailAddress ad PhoneNumber. currently i am doing like below

```
for(var i=0; i<json.length;i++){
       if((employeeCode==code)&&(emailAddress ==email)&&(PhoneNumber==phone)){
                     //here i am getting userId
        }   
    }
```

I want know if this is the correct way. If it is small json load it ok. but if it's large scale of data what i have to do.

Comment: Care to format your question properly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: Getting all existing keys in a JSON array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767133/javascript-getting-all-existing-keys-in-a-json-array)

Comment: Check the answer. It is easy with the use of map function.

Comment: @ShanmugapriyaD, it is working for you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the `map` function on the `Employee` array:

```js
var data =    {
"Employees" : [
{
"userId":"rirani",
"jobTitleName":"Developer",

"preferredFullName":"Romin Irani",
"employeeCode":"E1",
"region":"CA",
"phoneNumber":"408-1234567",
"emailAddress":"romin.k.irani@gmail.com"
},
{
"userId":"nirani",
"jobTitleName":"Developer",    
"preferredFullName":"Neil Irani",
"employeeCode":"E2",
"region":"CA",
"phoneNumber":"408-1111111",
"emailAddress":"neilrirani@gmail.com"
}
]

};

var code ='E2' , email ='neilrirani@gmail.com' , phone = '408-1111111', userId;
data.Employees.map(x=>{
   if(x.employeeCode == code && x.phoneNumber == phone && x.emailAddress== email){
     userId = x.userId;
  }
});

console.log(userId);
```

Comment: This is not the purpose of the `map` method. `map` method is used to create another array by applying a `callback` provided function for every item from `array` and returns a new array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find` method which accepts a `callback` provided function applied on every item in the array.

> The find() method returns the value of the first element in the array
>   that satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise undefined is
>   returned.

```js
let emailAddress="neilrirani@gmail.com";
let phone="408-1111111";
let code="E2";
let Employees = [
{
"userId":"rirani",
"jobTitleName":"Developer",
"preferredFullName":"Romin Irani",
"employeeCode":"E1",
"region":"CA",
"phoneNumber":"408-1234567",
"emailAddress":"romin.k.irani@gmail.com"
},
{
"userId":"nirani",
"jobTitleName":"Developer",    
"preferredFullName":"Neil Irani",
"employeeCode":"E2",
"region":"CA",
"phoneNumber":"408-1111111",
"emailAddress":"neilrirani@gmail.com"
}
];
let employee=Employees.find(function(employee){
    return employee.emailAddress==emailAddress && employee.phoneNumber==phone && employee.employeeCode==code;
});
console.log(employee.userId);
```