# Struts2 with rest-plugin: Map JSON value to ENUM

Tags: java, json, rest, struts2

I'm using Struts2 with the rest-plugin to build a RESTful web services. Serializing from Java objects to JSON was a breeze - everything mapped correctly and beautifully. Receiving JSON and attempting to map it to Java objects is a whole different issue.

I ran into 2 problems:

1) Could not convert JSON array to List. "Solved" it by using String[] instead.

2) There's an ENUM is the JSON like so:

```
{"feature":{"id":2,"enabled":true,"description":"one click transactions feature","type":"ONECLICK_OPTIN_TRANSACTIONS"},"countries":["SG"],"clientId":10}
```

"type" : "ONECLICK_OPTIN_TRANSACTIONS" should map to an ENUM in the Java object, but of course, Struts2 barfs instead.

Has anyone successfully done this?

For reference, this is the relevant portion of the exception:

```
Method public java.lang.String org.apache.commons.lang.exception.NestableRuntimeException.getMessage(int) threw an exception when invoked on net.sf.ezmorph.MorphException: com.foo.bar.entity.FeatureType
```

Thanks,
Shaun

Comment: What is the exception? Post a full stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not such thing as Enums in JSON. Of course there are work around to this like using a [hash table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820202/how-to-create-a-hashtable-of-json-objects-in-javascript) but it is always good to think in according to the technology.